# Delphi 10 Seattle missing libsqlib.a

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, interbase, delphi-10-seattle

I can't compile my multi-device iOS application, because there is an error:

[DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: libsqlib.a

I use Delphi 10 Seattle.

I didn'd find solution for this, only for the Delphi XE8 and XE5 libsqlib.a can be downloaded. But it doesn't work with these.

Can you help me?

Zoltán

Answer (score 1):

The `libsqlib.a` files for iOS are installed on my D10Seattle system in following directories:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice32\release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice32\debug
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice64\release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\iosDevice64\debug
```

There could be something wrong with your installation or missing/wrong search paths.
A reinstallation might resolve your problem.

Comment: Which version of D10 you have? I have Professional version. On my collegue's installation doesn't contain this file also. This file is only in the android\release folder.

Comment: So far, there has been no update.  Version 23.0.20618.2753

Comment: I'm using the professional edition with mobile add-on (included in my update service agreement).